# Importing DSpace in MyEclipse

Tags: myeclipse

M building a project from SVN and importing the DSpace in My Eclipse 2013.
It starts scanning of projects and stops at some after 90 or 93%...
It does scans for further files and stops there only.
Kindly Help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DSpace and can't tell from your question whether the scanning is related to that or not. We have had some issues with a few systems whereby the task that scans for projects to migrate from earlier releases takes a lot of system resource. There are fixes for this coming in the SR1 release, which is due imminently. However, the scanning can be turned off with this procedure:

Click on Window->Preferences then go to General->Startup and Shutdown. Deselect MyEclipse Migration Support and click OK. Now restart MyEclipse.

I hope this helps. For further support, please use the [MyEclipse Forums](http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums).